# when should I use a content provider in android

Tags: android, sqlite, caching, android-contentprovider

*I am trying to understand in what situation my app might use a Content Provider to manage its data*. I am not interested in providing data to other apps, just as a general abstraction/interface above sqlite.

So, for easy framing, my question is this: Does an app like Youtube need a content provider? I am asking the question in the context of a local cache. More broadly: does any app that behaves like a search engine need to use contentProvider/sqlite?

For instance I understand that a weather app might use a content provider since weather data does not change all that often and a 7-day forecast will not change from hour to hour. So in that sense I might use a contentProvider so as not to query the server each time a user checks but rather I might do the check, say, every three hours.

But for an app like Youtube, *where the user is allowed to search for data*, what would I put in a contentProvider and what advantage does such caching provide? Do I put the search result, playlist, favorites? Also might it make sense for Quora to cache the Trending stuff in a contentProvider since that might not change all that often?

Instead of a ContentProvider, should such data be stored in an in-memory cache? And yes do take into account that Youtube serves videos. I am really hoping to get some expert answers here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the ContentProvider is a kind of capsulation of data storage and it provides some interfaces for data operations like query, insertion, deletion and so on. Clients that uses ContentProvider does not care about how data are stored inside ContentProvider. ContentProvider can use database, files, or even temporarily generated data in memory. So the main purpose of ContentProvider is to facilitate data sharing among apps or processes.

It's better to use ContentProvider when data is local like contacts information, call logs, todo lists and so on. I don't think it is a good choice for Youtube to store videos locally since the amount of the data is unlimited. Youtube is designed to access data stored in remote web servers. But I don't mean Youtube won't use ContentProvider at all. There are still some kinds of data that can be stored locally for better user experience. For example Youtube may use ContentProvider to store a user's play history so that the user can browse his/her play history later even when the phone has no access to network.